# Can be found quadratic polynomial With integer coefficients to form of :

Tags: polynomials

Can be found quadratic polynomial With integer coefficients to form of :

$$1-):ax^2+bx+c:a\neq 0$$

$$2-):(a+1)x^2+(b+1)x+(c+1):a+1\neq 0$$

such that :Both have their roots integers ؟

thanks!!

Comment: Yes. For example, $\;a=-1,\,b=c=0\;$ .

Comment: @DonAntonio Just one ?!!Is it possible to obtain all
؟؟

Comment: I don't know. The question asked about finding one such quadratic and there you have my example.

Comment: @DonAntonio. The roots of the polynomial for integers are.

Comment: @DonAntonio .(a) in Polynomial (1) Same (a )in Polynomial( 2)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean in your last two comments. Sorry.

Comment: @DonAntonio@DonAntonio .(a,b,c) in$ ax^2+bx+c$   Same    (a,b,c )     in            $$(a+1)x^2+(b+1)x+(c+1)$$    they are the same

Comment: Yes, I know: that's what I wrote **exactly**. with $\;a=-1,\,b=c=0\;$ ,  the pol. in (1) is $\;-x^2\;$ , with its double root $\;0\;$ an integer, and in the pol. (2) we have $$a+1=0,\,b+1=c+1=1\implies 0\cdot x^2+x+1=x+1$$ and its root is also an integer: $\;-1\;$ . What's the problem?

Comment: @DonAntonio Right but:
 inquadratic polynomial :$a \neq 0, a+1  \neq 0$

Comment: You should read *carefully* what you wrote: the name "quadratic" only appears for the first polynomial in (1), **not** for the second one in (2) . Either you accept the example or you write carefully **all** your conditions.

Comment: @DonAntonio :(((( excuse me Professor .

Comment: You're excused and even forgotten but be more careful next time. This is mathematics, we need to as precise as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a quadratic polynomial to have integer zeros, it is necessary that the leading coefficient is a factor of the other two. So if $a\neq0$ and $a\neq-1$, you must have all of 
$$
a\mid b, \quad a\mid c,\quad a+1\mid b+1,\quad  a+1\mid c+1.
$$
By the Chinese remainder theorem this implies that both $b$ and $c$ are congruent to $a$ modulo $a(a+1)$. This means that modulo $a(a+1)$ the first equation looks like
$$
ax^2+ax+a\equiv0\pmod{a(a+1)}
$$
and the second 
$$
(a+1)x^2+(a+1)x+(a+1)\equiv0\pmod{a(a+1)}.
$$
Cancelling the obvious factors shows us that both congruences
$$
x^2+x+1\equiv0\pmod a
$$
and $$x^2+x+1\equiv0\pmod {a+1}$$ have integer solutions. But either $a$ or $a+1$ is even, and here $x^2+x+1$ is always odd, so this is impossible.

Therefore either $a=0$ or $a=-1$, and one of the equations is linear.